# How to move button outside of his parent with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget, tk-toolkit

I'm currently trying to move a button by using drag and drop with tkinter.
The problem is that when I'm trying to move my button, it's working but I can't move it outside his parent:
I have a LabelFrame which contains several LabelFrame with buttons. I'm trying to drag and drop a button from a LabelFrame to the other one but when the button is going outside of his parent, it "disappears".
I'm using the method "place" of the widget to move it during my drag.

I'm not sure if my problem is really understandable. I'll put some codes if it isn't to explain it better.

Comment: You can't directly do this. a widget is confined to the space it's parent occupies. You could write some code to detect when the widget touched the edge of the parent and then redraw it inside a different parent, but this would require an astronomical amount of work for such a small task (unless anyone knows of an incredibly easy way to do this).

Comment: I've been working a lot with Tkinter over the past couple weeks, I don't know if what you're asking is possible. Parents truncate children inherently, from what I can tell. My work around was creating a "GUIHolder" class and using that to maintain lineage (ie parents/children). Then all objects can be directly parented to the root, allowing for things to seem to move outside their parent.

Comment: If you can provide a **minimal**, **complete** and **verifiable** example following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can *try* and put something together to demonstrate how this would be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Widgets exist in a hierarchy, and every widget will be visually clipped by its parent. Since you want a widget to appear in different frames at different times, it simply cannot be a child of either frame. Instead, make it a child of the parent of the frames. You can then use `place` (or `pack` or `grid`) to put the widget in either frame by using the `in_` parameter.

Here's an example. It doesn't use drag and drop in order to keep the code compact, but it illustrates the principle. Click on the button to move it from one frame to the other.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.lf1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root, text="Choose me!", width=200, height=200)
        self.lf2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root, text="No! Choose me!", width=200, height=200)

        self.lf1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.lf2.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Click me", command=self.on_click)
        self.button.place(in_=self.lf1, x=20, y=20)

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def on_click(self):
        current_frame = self.button.place_info().get("in")
        new_frame = self.lf1 if current_frame == self.lf2 else self.lf2
        self.button.place(in_=new_frame, x=20, y=20)


Example().start()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It's helping me a lot, I didn't know the in_ parameter and I'm going to use it to make what I want.!

Comment: This is also news to me. That looks like a really useful parameter... I wonder what some practical uses would be of `in_`.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: the main practical use is more-or-less this right here. In the tcl/tk world I used it fairly often, but virtually never use it with python/tkinter. `in_` is definitely one of the more obscure aspects of tkinter.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the info :)