# Dynamically adding matplotlib figures of different sizes to a tkinter window

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am working on an application that dynamically organises multiple `matplotlib` figures in a `tkinter` window. I want the figures to be able to be of different size, but to always 'snap' to the available space. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47291151/2454357) I came up with a solution that suits my needs, but I'm having the problem that figures might not be displayed correctly when I add new figures to the window. Once the window is resized, all figures are again displayed correctly.

In my application, I organise figures with the `pack` command, restricting figures to be arranged either vertically or horizontally within one frame. If I then want to add more figures in the other direction, I replace a figure with an empty frame, move that figure to the new frame and then add new figures which are packed in the new direction.

I was trying very hard to come up with a good MCVE, but the sample code became quite long anyway -- sorry about that:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

try:
    import Tkinter as tk 
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

try:
    import ttk           
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class FigFrame(FigureCanvasTkAgg):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.fig,self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2,2))
        FigureCanvasTkAgg.__init__(self, self.fig, master=parent)
        self.cid = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('resize_event', self.on_resize)


    def on_resize(self, event):
        self.fig.tight_layout()
        self.fig.canvas.draw()


    def pack(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.get_tk_widget().pack(*args, **kwargs)


    def pack_forget(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.get_tk_widget().pack_forget(*args, **kwargs)


def add_figure():
    """
    hard-coding the interactive addition of another figure:

    replacing figure2 with a tk.Frame, placing figure2 inside that
    frame, and adding figure 5 right of figure 2.
    """

    global figure5
    global frame3
    global frame3_widgets

    ##creating frame
    frame3 = tk.Frame(frame2)
    frame3_widgets = []

    ##replacing figure2 with frame3:
    idx = frame2_widgets.index(figure2)
    frame2_widgets[idx]=frame3

    ##placing figure2 in frame3
    frame3_widgets.append(figure2)

    ##creating figure5:
    figure5 = FigFrame(root)
    figure5.ax.set_title('figure 5')
    figure5.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both', in_=frame3)
    frame3_widgets.append(figure5)

    ##repacking everything:
    for widget in frame1_widgets:
        widget.pack_forget()

    for widget in frame1_widgets:
        widget.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both', in_=frame1)

    for widget in frame2_widgets:
        widget.pack_forget()

    for widget in frame2_widgets:
        widget.pack(side='top', expand=True, fill='both', in_=frame2)

    for widget in frame3_widgets:
        widget.pack_forget()

    for widget in frame3_widgets:
        widget.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both', in_=frame3)






if __name__ == '__main__':

    root=tk.Tk()
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exit)

    frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
    frame1.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')
    frame1_widgets=[]

    figure1 = FigFrame(root)
    figure1.ax.set_title('figure 1')
    figure1.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both', in_=frame1)
    frame1_widgets.append(figure1)

    frame2 = tk.Frame(frame1)
    frame2.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')
    frame2_widgets=[]
    frame1_widgets.append(frame2)

    figure2 = FigFrame(root)
    figure2.ax.set_title('figure 2')
    figure2.pack(side='top', expand=True, fill='both', in_=frame2)
    frame2_widgets.append(figure2)

    figure3 = FigFrame(root)
    figure3.ax.set_title('figure 3')
    figure3.pack(side='top', expand=True, fill='both', in_=frame2)
    frame2_widgets.append(figure3)

    figure4 = FigFrame(root)
    figure4.ax.set_title('figure 4')
    figure4.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both', in_=frame1)
    frame1_widgets.append(figure4)


    ##here I simulate the interactive part that adds a new figure:
    root.after(1000,add_figure)
    ##add_figure()  ##<-- this line instead of the above displays the figures correctly

    root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, I first create four figures, which are displayed when `root.mainloop()` is called. To then simulate the dynamic addition of another figure, I add a delayed call to the function `add_figure()`, which then only is processed once the original four figures have been displayed.

Once `add_figure()` is called, `figure 2` is resized to half its original width and `figure 5` is placed in the remaining space. However, in the process `figure 2` 'disappears' and only reappears once the window is resized (using the mouse). I also get a `matplotlib` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 388, in process
    proxy(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 228, in __call__
    return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
  File "subframe_problem.py", line 30, in on_resize
    self.fig.tight_layout()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 2276, in tight_layout
    self.subplots_adjust(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 2088, in subplots_adjust
    self.subplotpars.update(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 241, in update
    raise ValueError('left cannot be >= right')
ValueError: left cannot be >= right
```

The error comes from my use of `tight_layout()` upon figure-resize, which makes me think that something is happening too soon or too late when the space is re-distributed.

If I don't delay the call to `add_figure`, i.e. if I replace `root.after(1000,add_figure)` with `add_figure` (which is not what I want, because the user should be able to add figures dynamically), all figures are displayed correctly.

The problem occurs both with Python 3.6 and 2.7. I've only tried the code on macos.

Comment: I don't have any solution to this problem. But did you consider making one big matplotlib canvas and adding subplots to it, instead of moving tk frames around?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I did, but what is missing from my MCVE are the possibilities to dynamically change (with mainly mouse clicks) what is plotted, changing ranges, colormaps, projections, etc., especially mixing Basemap figures and 'normal' matplotlib plots. Maybe I don't understand matplotlib's own capabilities well enough, but I had come to the conclusion that I need another tool to achieve everything I have in mind.

Comment: There should not be any problem with mixing basemap and "normal" plots. I think the one main advantage of your solution here is that you can redraw part of the complete figure (because each "subplot" *is*  a figure), which makes this faster in theory. Can you reproduce this without any matplotlib plots involved? That could allow some tkinter expert to provide a solution.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I made a quick test with `tk.Frames` of different background colours, which made the problem go away, so apparently this is indeed something about the interplay between matplotlib and tkinter.