# tkinter scrollbar only scrolls downwards and cuts off content

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

**EDIT** [resolved]

based on the [answer from Thingamabobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70486666/tkinter-scrollbar-only-scrolls-downwards-and-cuts-off-content/70487596#70487596) below, the approach simply turns out to be making sure the elements you spawn are allocated to correct parents.

It is worthwhile to create a frame just to hold every scrollable element since you can't move widgets around between parents when using `pack/place`. So a common parents between all `movable` elements will give you the freedom to move them around, again just create a holder frame. See the answer and discussion below for more details.

EDIT2

[Bryan's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70486666/tkinter-scrollbar-only-scrolls-downwards-and-cuts-off-content/70497728#70497728) has very good info and an alternate approach using just a canvas. The core concepts still stand the same.

**original question begins here**

---

### The situation

So based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290791/how-to-move-button-outside-of-his-parent-with-tkinter/47291151#47291151) by Bryan, I used this approach to spawn widgets on a `scrollable frame` (which is basically a `Canvas` wrapping a frame inside as we know cause Frames don't have scroll attributes).

The widgets in this case are just `tk.Button`s which I spawn in a loop using lambda to preserve state. That aspect is completely fine.

### The issue

Now everything works fine except when I spawn more elements (again just buttons), they seem to be cut off. and I can't seem to scroll down to see the remaining ones. I am only able to scroll upwards only to see empty space.

**please see the video below to see what I mean** (excuse my horrible color choices, this is for a quick demo)

[image]

In the video, there are more elements below `template47` but I can not scroll to them. I can scroll upwards but it's just lonely up there. All the names are actually buttons with zero `bd` and `HLthickness`.

### what I have tried

To begin, my first instinct was to attach a `ttk.scrollbar` to the `canvas+frame`, which I did but observed the exact same behavior.

Then I tried to see if i could use `.moveTo('1.0')` to scroll down to last entry and then since upward scrolling works already, shouldn't have an issue. But this didn't do anything either. Still the elements were cut off, and it obviously messed up upward scrolling too.

I don't think I can use `pack/grid` geoManagers since as the answer by bryan i linked to above suggests, using `place` with its `in_` arg is the preferred way. If it is possible otherwise, let me know though.

#### my use case in a nutshell

as depicted in the answer linked above, I also have two frames, and I'm using the on_click callback function to switch parents (a lot like in example code in answer). Turned out place was the best bet to achieve this.
and it is, all of that aspect is working well. It's just the scroll thingy which doesn't work.

### some code (dare i say MCVE)

how i bind to mousewheel

```py
    def _bound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)

    def _unbound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")
```

creating the window

```py
self.canvas.create_window((5, 6), window=self.scrolled_frame, anchor="w")
```

ad of course the widgets inside

```py
        for f in self.fav_templates:
            btn = tk.Button(self.root, text='text', command=lambda te=f: self._on_click(te))

            btn.place(in_=self.ft_frame, x=20, y=p)
```

### So

I'm sure above snippets would give idea of what I've done. If someone needs me to create a complete MCVE they can run, happy to do that, lemme know.

**What did I miss in the setup?** any ideas or suggestion are welcome.

Thank You :)

Comment: _"dare i say MCVE"_ - that is far from being a [mcve] because it won't run as posted.

Comment: If all you're doing is a vertical stack of widgets,  you don't need the complexity of the frame-in-a-canvas trick. You can directly add the buttons to the canvas.

Comment: @BryanOakley oh i know. i meant to say *i shouldn't dare to call this an MCVE*. it was just some snippets. 

about this `button in canvas` instead of `frame-in-canvas` approach, personally i would have loved just the frames to have scroll attributes.

but do ya think I'd be able to scroll seamlessly if i spawn buttons on canvas as you say (using `create_window` i presume) and binding scroll events to canvas itself?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can scroll anything on a canvas. Scrolling a series of buttons is no different than scrolling a single frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are using `place` and with place you will be the allmighty over the widget, means there will be no [requested size](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkLib/GeomReq.html) to the master or any other magic tkinter provides in the background. So I do recommand to use another geometry manager that does that magic for you like pack. Also note that I set the anchor to `nw`.

In addition it appears that you can only use the optional argument `in_` in a common master. So the key of that concept is to have an holder frame that is used as master parameter and use the `in_` for  children that are able to hold widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        test_frame = tk.Frame(self.root,height=200,width=400,bg='orange')
        test_frame.pack()
        self.DISPLAY_WIDTH = 200
        self.DISPLAY_HEIGHT= 200
        self.create_holder()
        self.create_displays()
        self.add_scrollbars()
        self.populate_holder()
    def create_holder(self):
        '''creates a canvas for the displays and is needed
         to have a common border/window'''
        self.holder = tk.Canvas(self.root,width=self.DISPLAY_WIDTH*2,height=self.DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
        self.holder_frame = tk.Frame(self.holder)
        self.holder.create_window((5, 6), window=self.holder_frame, anchor="nw")
        self.holder.pack()
    def create_displays(self):
        '''creates 2 displays to have seperate scrollregions'''
        self.cnvs1 = tk.Canvas(self.holder_frame,
                               width=self.DISPLAY_WIDTH,
                               height=self.DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
        self.cnvs2 = tk.Canvas(self.holder_frame,
                               width=self.DISPLAY_WIDTH,
                               height=self.DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
        self.lf1 = tk.Frame(self.cnvs1);self.cnvs1.create_window((5, 6), window=self.lf1, anchor="nw")
        self.lf2 = tk.Frame(self.cnvs2);self.cnvs2.create_window((5, 6), window=self.lf2, anchor="nw")
    def add_scrollbars(self):        
        self.vsb1 = tk.Scrollbar(self.holder_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.cnvs1.yview)
        self.vsb2 = tk.Scrollbar(self.holder_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.cnvs2.yview)        
        self.cnvs1.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb1.set)
        self.lf1.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.cnvs2.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb2.set)
        self.lf2.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
    def populate_holder(self):
        self.cnvs1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.vsb1.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.cnvs2.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.vsb2.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        for i in range(20):
            button = tk.Button(self.holder_frame,text="Click me")
            button.config(command=lambda b=button:self.on_click(b))
            button.pack(in_=self.lf1)
    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.cnvs1.configure(scrollregion=self.cnvs1.bbox("all"))
        self.cnvs2.configure(scrollregion=self.cnvs2.bbox("all"))

    def on_click(self,button):
        current_frame = button.pack_info().get("in")
        new_frame = self.lf1 if current_frame == self.lf2 else self.lf2
        button.pack(in_=new_frame)


Example().start()
```

Comment: I can use `in_` with `pack`!!!?? That's a game changer lol. btw i do not need `anchor=tk.NW` but appreciate the mention. my anchor is CENTER for most widgets. 

i thought once i define a widget in a parent, i can't change it with other managers. That changes things. I'll try it and see what it gets me.

Comment: Okay i tried this. seems to work largely but it takes over other widgets which are totally separate frames when i scroll up. [This is how](https://imgur.com/a/urUQdsu) it appears to be when scrolling. No content is cut off. shows all elements

Comment: @PSSolanki not sure what you did there. Cant reproduce your issue, you will need to share your code.

Comment: I'll try to create a MCVE actually. I just have a few frames at the top. Creating an MCVE was a bit tricky due to other components but I'll try.

Comment: @PSSolanki I dont mind if you go for the full tkinter related code.

Comment: actually i just made relevant changes to your version and looks like i'm  able to reproduce the issue. Will share once i have a shareable version.  Highly appreciate the help :)

Comment: alrightyy, [here](https://pastebin.com/NzA4re16) is the same code modified to reproduce. 
this happens with just one frame also btw. so when you run it, you'll notice it taking up space in the top frame which it shouldn't (that's why i gave that frame a different color for better visibility).

Comment: @PSSolanki Sorry, took me awhaile to figure out my own mistake and its intresting as well. Do `button = tk.Button(self.lf1,text="Click me")` in your shared exampel and the left one will work fine while the right one is still be broken. The master parameter is the root window `tk.Tk()` by default and thats seems to cause this behavior. But still, it seems like a bug to me.

Comment: wait i added the parent arg to both buttons, and it seems to be well for both the cases. Here i get the desired behavior when i run [this modified version](https://pastebin.com/cPhz3fjy) what kinda bug did ya see when you ran it btw?

Comment: @PSSolanki wait.. this dosent work if you press a button. Im working something out for you.

Comment: just tried it. that was my initial thought actually. the fact that defining a button explicitly with a parent name would prolly bind that widget to that parent, disallowing pack/grid geometry managers to put it in another parent. 

(also consider moving the discussion to chat as SO recommends if ya prefer that)

Comment: UPDATE: personally i'm able to work with the above scenario, I'll just reload the concerned frames and respawn the elements with updated lists. So FOR MY PERSONAL use, i'm good. But i believe this would be a good idea to figure a general solution if possible to this case. I originally wanted to implement something like `drag and drop` but had to drop due to not very extensive support for that in tk.

Comment: @PSSolanki I have made an working exampel. If you would test it in your envoirment I would be glad.

Comment: hmmm. a wrapper frame, i had that idea for a brief moment when i saw the buttons getting extended to `root`. I like it. and yes, it works in my environment. Appreciate the help on this one. I'll update the question with status :)

Comment: Thanks, was an intresting question. Glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a vertical stack of widgets, you're overcomplicating the solution when you embed a frame in a canvas. Instead, you can create the buttons directly in the canvas. The only time an embedded frame is useful is when you want to leverage the power of `pack` or `grid` to arrange the widgets into a complex layout. In this case you're creating a vertical stack, so the frame is unnecessary.

Here are a few things to notice about the following code:

- the buttons are a child of the canvas, not a child of root. I don't know why you were making the buttons the child of the root window since they are going in the canvas. They need to be a child of the canvas so that they don't draw outside of the border of the canvas.
- a property named `lasty` will return the bottom y coordinate. Every new button will get added below this coordinate.
- this code doesn't use `self.fav_templates` for the sake of brevity.

---

```
import tkinter as tk

class ScrolledButtons(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=self.canvas.yview, orient="vertical")
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        for n in range(20):
            x = 2
            y = self.lasty + 2
            btn = tk.Button(self.canvas, text=f'Button #{n}', command=lambda te=n: self._on_click(te))
            self.canvas.create_window(20, y, anchor="nw", window=btn)
        bbox = self.canvas.bbox("all")
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, bbox[2], bbox[3]))

    @property
    def lasty(self):
        bbox = self.canvas.bbox("all")
        lasty = bbox[3] if bbox else 0
        return lasty

root = tk.Tk()
w = ScrolledButtons(root)
w.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

---

[image: screenshot]

Comment: that's a very good solution. Appreciate it. *"the buttons are a child of canvas, not root"* - yeah i eventually realized the same after trying out a few things when i noticed the buttons spanning space outside the canvas. I remember the reason was because i had `root` when i was using `place` and i forgot to change it to correct parent when changing to pack. I did mention the same in the updated question.